# Using WMS server parameter SLD

Tags: geoserver, wms, sld, getmap

I have an issue with using the parameter SLD in GetMap when using the WMS service via the geoserver's API. When passing a style into the parameters of a GET call to a WMS layer using the STYLES parameter I get the desired result. However, when I copy and paste the sld code into a file on GitHub and use the SLD parameter accordingly, everything is grey.

Any idea?

Geoserver version: 2.19.1

[Using parameter styles](https://stage.xcube-geodb.brockmann-consult.de/geoserver/eea-urban-atlas/wms?service=WMS&version=1.1.0&request=GetMap&layers=eea-urban-atlas%3Aeea-urban-atlas_SI001L2_LJUBLJANA_UA2018&bbox=4638735.0%2C2524481.25%2C4704972.5%2C2594978.75&width=721&height=768&srs=EPSG%3A3035&styles=ljubilana&format=image/png)

[Using parameter SLD](https://stage.xcube-geodb.brockmann-consult.de/geoserver/eea-urban-atlas/wms?service=WMS&version=1.1.0&request=GetMap&layers=eea-urban-atlas%3Aeea-urban-atlas_SI001L2_LJUBLJANA_UA2018&bbox=4638735.0%2C2524481.25%2C4704972.5%2C2594978.75&width=721&height=768&srs=EPSG%3A3035&format=image/png&SLD=https://github.com/dzelge/test-gha/blob/main/ljubilana.sld?raw=true)

Comment: So it's giving you the default style https://stage.xcube-geodb.brockmann-consult.de/geoserver/eea-urban-atlas/wms?service=WMS&version=1.1.0&request=GetMap&layers=eea-urban-atlas%3Aeea-urban-atlas_SI001L2_LJUBLJANA_UA2018&bbox=4638735.0%2C2524481.25%2C4704972.5%2C2594978.75&width=721&height=768&srs=EPSG%3A3035&styles&format=image/png

Comment: Is dynamic styling enabled ~ https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/services/wms/webadmin.html#disabling-usage-of-dynamic-styling-in-getmap-and-getfeatureinfo-requests

Comment: A request without the layers parameter (which is allowed)  gives an exception `ServiceException>Error while getting SLD.  See the log for details.` so either the server can't see the SLD or there is some other issue with the SLD

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! You need to turn up the logging level to developer in the global settings page, and then make the request again. Then [edit] your question with the **relevant** part of the log file.

Answer (score 1):

Your SLD on GitHub has:

```
<sld:NamedLayer>
    <sld:Name>CH001L2_ZURICH_UA2018</sld:Name>
```

The SLD schema (http://schemas.opengis.net/sld/1.0.0/StyledLayerDescriptor.xsd) tells us that:

```
<xsd:element name="NamedLayer">
    <xsd:annotation>
        <xsd:documentation>
    A NamedLayer is a layer of data that has a name advertised by a WMS.
  </xsd:documentation>
```

But the [WMS](https://stage.xcube-geodb.brockmann-consult.de/geoserver/eea-urban-atlas/wms?service=WMS&version=1.3.0&request=GetCapabilities) has no layer called `CH001L2_ZURICH_UA2018` only layers `eea-urban-atlas_DE002L1_HAMBURG_UA2018` and `eea-urban-atlas_SI001L2_LJUBLJANA_UA2018`

So the SLD is not applied, and you get the default.